# Typical duration of bonds purchased in QE

Tags: money-supply, quantitative-easing

I know that QE involves the purchasing of government bonds by the central bank "printing money" but I am curious about what the typical time to maturity of those bonds are. I.e. the typical time before the central bank is faced with the choice of "un-printing" that money (taking it out of the economy) or doing some more QE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper is a few years old. You might want to look at page 6.
Briefly, it varies by country and across time.

https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/quarterly-refunding/Documents/February2015TBACCharge1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It changes over time. Any textual summary is probably going to end up out of date.

If the purchases are a large portion of securities outstanding - which is the case - the central bank has no choice but to buy what is available.

[Link to NY Fed page with data.](https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/soma-holdings)